# MVP GWT - problem injecting EventBus

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, mvp

Weird problem, when i inject EventBus e got an exception. The project is gwt using mvp

Here is the sample code.

Gin

```
public interface AppGinjector extends Ginjector
{
  EventBus getEventBus();
  PlaceManager getPlaceManager();
}
```

Here is the entry point

```
public class MvpEntryPoint implements EntryPoint
{
AppGinjector ginjector = GWT.create(AppGinjector.class);

public void onModuleLoad()
{

  EventBus eventBus = ginjector.geEventBus();
  HelloWorldPanel display = new HelloWorldPanel();
  HelloWorldPresenter presenter = new HelloWorldPresenter( display, eventBus );

  presenter.bind();

  RootPanel.get().add( presenter.getDisplay().asWidget() );

  PlaceManager placeManager =  ginjector.getPlaceManager();
  placeManager.fireCurrentPlace();

}
```

i use gin 1.0 , gwt-presenter

Any has any idea?

Thanks

Edit:

The exception is

```
ERROR: Deferred binding result type 'net.customware.gwt.presenter.client.EventBus' should not be abstract. 
ERROR: Unable to load module entry point class com.gmgsys.mvpEntryPoint.client.MvpEntryPoint (see associated exception for details). java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'net.customware.gwt.presenter.client.EventBus' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
...........................
```

also the gwt.xml

```
  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
    <entry-point class='com.gmgsys.mvpEntryPoint.client.MvpEntryPoint'/>
    <inherits name='net.customware.gwt.presenter.Presenter' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the AbstractPresenterModule class which makes sure that EventBus is bound to SimpleEventBus:

```
bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

It should be something like that:

```
public class MyClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
  protected void configure() {
     bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
     // more bindings here
  }
}
```

And you have to annotate your Ginjector

```
@GinModules({ MyClientModule .class })
public interface AppGinjector extends Ginjector
{
  EventBus getEventBus();
  PlaceManager getPlaceManager();
}
```